# Why is dnsmasq forwarding already resolved addresses?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns, dnsmasq

I can ping the host:

```
dig registry.mynet
```

And the DNS server does what is expected:

```
dnsmasq[1]: 895 127.0.0.1/44580 query[A] registry.mynet from 127.0.0.1
dnsmasq[1]: 895 127.0.0.1/44580 /etc/hosts registry.mynet is 42.42.42.42
```

But if I try a more complex request, it takes a long time:

```
» time http -h http://registry.mynet/v2/_catalog?n=100
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 97
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 23 Mar 2018 10:42:13 GMT
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Server: nginx/1.13.9
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

real    0m15.297s
user    0m0.252s
sys     0m0.028s
```

And this has nothing to do with the service (which is very responsive). This is because the DNS server does something strange:

```
dnsmasq[1]: 887 127.0.0.1/53345 query[A] registry.mynet from 127.0.0.1
dnsmasq[1]: 887 127.0.0.1/53345 /etc/hosts registry.mynet is 42.42.42.42
dnsmasq[1]: 888 127.0.0.1/53345 query[AAAA] registry.mynet from 127.0.0.1
dnsmasq[1]: 888 127.0.0.1/53345 forwarded registry.mynet to 208.67.220.220
dnsmasq[1]: 888 127.0.0.1/53345 forwarded registry.mynet to 8.8.4.4
dnsmasq[1]: 888 127.0.0.1/53345 forwarded registry.mynet to 8.8.8.8
dnsmasq[1]: 888 127.0.0.1/53345 forwarded registry.mynet to 8.8.8.8

dnsmasq[1]: 889 127.0.0.1/53345 query[A] registry.mynet from 127.0.0.1
dnsmasq[1]: 889 127.0.0.1/53345 /etc/hosts registry.mynet is 42.42.42.42
dnsmasq[1]: 890 127.0.0.1/53345 query[AAAA] registry.mynet from 127.0.0.1
dnsmasq[1]: 890 127.0.0.1/53345 forwarded registry.mynet to 208.67.220.220
dnsmasq[1]: 890 127.0.0.1/53345 forwarded registry.mynet to 8.8.4.4
dnsmasq[1]: 890 127.0.0.1/53345 forwarded registry.mynet to 8.8.8.8
dnsmasq[1]: 890 127.0.0.1/53345 forwarded registry.mynet to 8.8.8.8

dnsmasq[1]: 891 127.0.0.1/41484 query[A] registry.mynet from 127.0.0.1
dnsmasq[1]: 891 127.0.0.1/41484 /etc/hosts registry.mynet is 42.42.42.42
dnsmasq[1]: 892 127.0.0.1/58752 query[AAAA] registry.mynet from 127.0.0.1
dnsmasq[1]: 892 127.0.0.1/58752 forwarded registry.mynet to 208.67.220.220
dnsmasq[1]: 892 127.0.0.1/58752 forwarded registry.mynet to 8.8.4.4
dnsmasq[1]: 892 127.0.0.1/58752 forwarded registry.mynet to 8.8.8.8
dnsmasq[1]: 892 127.0.0.1/58752 forwarded registry.mynet to 8.8.8.8
```

I have two questions:

- the DNS server does find the right answer (`/etc/hosts registry.mynet is 42.42.42.42`): why is processing continuing?
- what do the "forwarded" entries mean?

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

```
dig registry.mynet
```

Only performs IPv4 queries (`[A]` queries). Your `dnsmasq` is replying to those queries just fine. You can force `dig` to do `AAAA` queries by doing:

```
dig registry.mynet AAAA
```

From the logs, you can see that `http` is sending IPv4 and IPv6 queries (`[AAAA]` queries). Your `dnsmasq` is replying to the former, but not the latter maybe because you have not configured IPv6 addresses for your hosts.

You could avoid this by making sure that `dnsmasq` is not forwarding requests for hosts in your network:

```
local=/mynet/
```